# cross feature selectors in new ngrx14+

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular14, ngrx-selectors

i'm trying to use the new syntax createFeature() for my new angular project
but there is this one thing stopping me, i don't know how to implement cross feature selectors using the new api
i'm reading from this link:
https://dev.to/this-is-angular/the-new-ngrx-lf1

in the "Extra selectors on feature" it explains how to add your own selectors, here the relevant code (see 'extraSelectors' prop)

```
export const Feature = createFeature({
    name: 'feature',
    reducer: createReducer(
        initialState,
        on(
            FeatureActions.loadFeature,
            (state) => ({
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            }),
        ),
        on(
            FeatureActions.loadFeatureSuccess,
            (state, { data }) => ({
                ...state,
                data,
                loading: false,
            }),
        ),
        on(
            FeatureActions.loadFeatureFailure,
            (state, { error }) => ({
                ...state,
                error,
                loading: false,
            }),
        ),
    ),
    extraSelectors: ({selectData}) => ({
        selectDataAsArray: createSelector(
            selectData,
            (data) => Object.values(data)
        ),
    }),
});
```

my doubts: what exactly is "selectData" there? And more importantly how can i load
another feature selector if i want to create a new selector based on different features?
i guess for cross selectors i still have to do the usual way, like:

```
export const selectCrossFeatureExampleSelector= createSelector(
  selectFeature1Something,
  selectFeature2Something,
  (something: Feature1Obj, somethingElse: Feature2Obj) => ({ something, somethingElse })
);
```

where selectFeature1Something and selectFeature2Something are defined in 'extraSelectors' of the related features?

Thanks